# How can I have a loading window appear whilst a process is running?

Tags: asynchronous, javafx, ipc, scalafx

I have a ScalaFX application that I would like to call a python script upon the clicking of an imageview. This python script will then write to a text file that the ScalaFX application will read from later. My current issue is that whilst the python script is running, I would like a loading screen to be shown but I'm having difficulties with this.

How the scene is invoked

```
new Menu("Floor Plan Gen") {
        items = List(new MenuItem("Select Image") {
          onAction = _ => {
            val fileChooser   = new FileChooser()
            fileChooser.initialDirectory =
              new File(System.getProperty("user.home"))
            fileChooser.title = "Select Image"
            val extensionList = List("*.png", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.gif")
            fileChooser.extensionFilters.add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
              "Image Files",
              extensionList.toSeq
            ))
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage) match {
              case file: File =>
                println(
                  s"file location = ${file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()}"
                )
                val bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file)
                val image: Image  = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null)
                if (image.exception.value == null) {
                  val newWindow = new Stage()
                  val scene     = GraphGenWindow(
                    image,
                    model,
                    controller,
                    file.toPath().toString()
                  )
                  newWindow.resizable = false
                  newWindow.setTitle("Select Room")
                  newWindow.setScene(scene)
                  newWindow.show()
                } else {
                  controller.showError(
                    "Error",
                    "Error loading file.",
                    s"Failed to load file."
                  )
                }

              case _ =>
            }
          }
        })
      }
```

My first attempt

```
...Scene def....
onMouseClicked = event => {
    val x               = event.getX()
    val y               = event.getY()
    val roomFindCommand =
      Seq("python3", scriptLocation, fileName, x.toString(), y.toString())
    loadingWindow.show()
    roomFindCommand.!
    loadingWindow.close()
  }
```

When the screen is clicked, then the program freezes until the python script fully runs and then the loading window opens. I don't understand why this happens since the show() method should be invoked before the process begins. I understand that using ! will block the GUI thread but since I don't want the user to interact with the application and just wait whilst the script runs, then it should be ok. The close() method never seems to be invoked.

My second attempt

```
onMouseClicked = event => {
    val x               = event.getX()
    val y               = event.getY()
    val roomFindCommand =
      Seq("python3", scriptLocation, fileName, x.toString(), y.toString())
    
    val modelInvokerRunnable = new ModelInvokerRunnable(loadingWindow, roomFindCommand)
    val modelThread = new Thread(modelInvokerRunnable)
    modelThread.start()
    
    loadingWindow.show()
    
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable{
      override def run(): Unit = {
        println("HI THIS SHOULD RUN AT SOME POINT")
        loadingWindow.close()
      }
    })
  }
```

```
private class ModelInvokerRunnable(stage: Stage, script : Seq[String])    extends Runnable {

  override def run(): Unit                 = {
    script.!
  }
}
```

On this the loading window appeared straight after the click but again did not disappear afterwards. The print happened whilst the script was running but the window did not disappear.

---

On further investigation, when I reduced the onMouseClickEvent to just show and then close the stage, the stage stayed open which I find to be weird behaviour.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should be using a [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Comment: Off-topic, but the JavaFX image constructor can load a file with any of those image types you use.  You don't need to use ImageIO to load an image into an awt image, then convert that loaded image to a JavaFX image with SwingFXUtils.

Comment: Can you expand further on how I would use a task?

Comment: Not really, I have not used Scala in a long time, I can barely read it.  The Task javadoc does a good job of explaining its use with Java.  There are also numerous questions and answers on the use of Tasks and concurrency in JavaFX on this website if you use the search function.  [Oracle has a tutorial on concurrency and JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).   The rules are 1. Don't run blocking I/O or long computations on the JavaFX thread.  2. Don't invoke JavaFX APIs (or property changes) for the scene graph or stages from other threads.

Comment: Sample java code for [using a task](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098).

Comment: Incidentally, your use of runLater is incorrect.  There is no point in invoking runLater from the JavaFX thread.  The click handler is invoked from the JavaFX thread, so you are already on the JavaFX thread when you call runLater, so that code will likely be run very soon, not very much later, and not when your python task is complete.